How to properly bind descriptors to UBO descriptors
I sent up my texture's using Cherno's system.
I reached out to him on discord and he said that to get an individual texture to each individual object, I need to create separate descriptors for each object and bind it to the ubo descriptor.
So I created a Descriptor with the size as the number of gameobjects available to me:
std::vector<VkDescriptorSet> objectDescriptorSets(gameObjects.size());
for (int i = 0; i < gameObjects.size(); i++) {
    auto bufferInfo = uboBuffers[i]->descriptorInfo();

    lve::Texture player_Texture = lve::Texture(lveDevice, "Images/Sprites/Blaze.png");
    VkDescriptorImageInfo objectImageInfo = {};  // For object's texture
    objectImageInfo.sampler = player_Texture.getSampler();
    objectImageInfo.imageView = player_Texture.getImageView();
    objectImageInfo.imageLayout = player_Texture.getImageLayout();


    lve::LveDescriptorWriter(*globalSetLayout, *globalPool)
        .writeBuffer(0, &bufferInfo)
        .writeImage(1, &objectImageInfo)
        .build(objectDescriptorSets[i]);
}

I'm harding coding the texture for now.
Previously I had a global descriptor set:
auto globalSetLayout = lve::LveDescriptorSetLayout::Builder(lveDevice)
    .addBinding(0, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL_GRAPHICS)
    .addBinding(1, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER, VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT)
    .build();


lve::Texture texture = lve::Texture(lveDevice, "Images/Sprites/Nuradhi Logo copy.png");

VkDescriptorImageInfo imageInfo = {};
imageInfo.sampler = texture.getSampler();
imageInfo.imageView = texture.getImageView();
imageInfo.imageLayout = texture.getImageLayout();

std::vector<VkDescriptorSet> globalDescriptorSets(lve::LveSwapChain::MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);
for (int i = 0; i < globalDescriptorSets.size(); i++) {
    auto bufferInfo = uboBuffers[i]->descriptorInfo();
    lve::LveDescriptorWriter(*globalSetLayout, *globalPool)
        .writeBuffer(0, &bufferInfo)
        .writeImage(1,&imageInfo)
        .build(globalDescriptorSets[i]);
}

And it was rendered like this:
//while window is open, load objects...

//begin frame function will return a null ptr if the swap chain needs to be created
    auto commandBuffer = lveRenderer.beginFrame();
    if (!commandBuffer) continue;
    lveRenderer.beginSwapChainRenderPass(commandBuffer);
    int frameIndex = lveRenderer.getFrameIndex();
    lve::FrameInfo frameInfo{
        frameIndex,
        frameTime,
        commandBuffer,
        camera,
        globalDescriptorSets[frameIndex],
        gameObjects
    };

    

    simpleRenderSystem.getlvePipelinePtr()->bind(commandBuffer);
    lveRenderer.bindPipelineEssentials(commandBuffer, frameInfo);
    simpleRenderSystem.bindDescriptorSets(frameInfo);
    //update
    lve::GlobalUbo ubo{};
    ubo.projection = camera.getProjection();
    ubo.view = camera.getView();
    ubo.inverseView = camera.getInverseView();
    pointLightSystem.update(frameInfo, ubo);
    uboBuffers[frameIndex]->writeToBuffer(&ubo);
    uboBuffers[frameIndex]->flush();


    //order here matters
    simpleRenderSystem.renderGameObects(frameInfo);
    pointLightSystem.render(frameInfo);

    nrd::NrdDebugLinePipeline* debugPipelinePtr = simpleRenderSystem.getDebugPipelinePtr();
    debugPipelinePtr->bind(commandBuffer);
    lveRenderer.bindPipelineEssentials(commandBuffer, frameInfo);
    simpleRenderSystem.bindDescriptorSets(frameInfo); 
    
    
    //render
    // Update and render the debug line
    simpleRenderSystem.renderGameObects(frameInfo);
    lveRenderer.endSwapChainRenderPass(commandBuffer);
    lveRenderer.endFrame();

I'm still new to vulkan and I don't understand how binding works. I get Validation layer errors saying:
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo-apiVersion-07896 ] Object 0: handle = 0xcfcda0000000001e, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_POOL; | MessageID = 0x5584bd53 | vkAllocateDescriptorSets():  Unable to allocate 1 descriptors of type VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER from VkDescriptorPool 0xcfcda0000000001e[]. This pool only has 0 descriptors of this type remaining. The Vulkan spec states: If the VK_KHR_maintenance1 extension is not enabled and VkPhysicalDeviceProperties::apiVersion is less than Vulkan 1.1, descriptorPool must have enough free descriptor capacity remaining to allocate the descriptor sets of the specified layouts (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.275.0/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo-apiVersion-07896)

My poolsize is configure like this in the constructor:
globalPool = lve::LveDescriptorPool::Builder(lveDevice)
    .setMaxSets(lve::LveSwapChain::MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT)
    .addPoolSize(VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, lve::LveSwapChain::MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT)
    .addPoolSize(VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER,lve::LveSwapChain::MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT)
    .build();
loadGameObjects();

And in my main function I'm declaring a global set layout like this before the global descriptor:
auto globalSetLayout = lve::LveDescriptorSetLayout::Builder(lveDevice)
    .addBinding(0, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL_GRAPHICS)
    .addBinding(1, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER, VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT)
    .build();

Do I just replace the global descriptor and with the object descriptor? If that's the case, then what do I pass in place of frame index? Do I need to increase the pool and global set layout?
The entire script minus the most recent changes are available here:
https://github.com/VChuckShunA/Nuradhi-Engine/blob/master/Nuradhi%20Engine/nrd_test_level.cpp
